# Вывести большое количество обектов на Яндекс карту (>1000)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Нужно вывести на карту Яндекс больше 1000 объектов без кластеризации для определенной местности.
Сделал через objectManager как написано в документации
Но карта очень сильно тормозит, вплоть до зависания браузера.
Как можно добится нормальной скорости отображения объекто ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приложите код с вашей попыткой, если это возможно. Это поможет Сообществу быстрее понять проблему и предложить свою помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого лучше всего подойдет технология активных областей (hotspot layer):
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/hotspots/about-hotspots-docpage/

Comment: Как Вы думаете здесь какой метод используется. https://novostroev.ru/map-search/?f%5Bsquare-meter%5D=all&location-select=1%2C22%2C8705.  Мне нужно примерно такое-же

Comment: @СергейЯковлев Судя по html, тут используется отдельный canvas-слой leaflet'а, на котором программно нарисованы все точки - это другой подход. Сам я с канвасом толком не работал, так что что-либо подсказать не смогу. Касаемо технологии активных областей, о которой я изначально написал - ее использует [ЦИАН](https://www.cian.ru/map), например.